# DJANGO upgrade error: is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

This was my code in django 1.6 ( working good)
I upgraded to django 1.7.
First simplejson is depracated : i changed simplejson to json,But i receive the same error always 
is not json serializable.

Any ideas ?

**Views:**

```
def request_to_json(request):    
    post_data = request.body 
    json_data = simplejson.loads(post_data)
    return json_data 

def receiver(request):
    try:
        json_data = request_to_json(request)
        user_id=json_data['user_id'];
        site_id=json_data['site_id'];
  # A variable to return to the app
        response = 'Ok'

    except:
        response = sys.exc_info()[0]

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response))
```

**Error**

```
TypeError at /views/receiver/
<class 'TypeError'> is not JSON serializable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/views/receiver/
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
<class 'TypeError'> is not JSON serializable
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in default, line 173
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.EXE
Python Version: 3.4.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\workspace-eclipse\\IndoorPositioning',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-5.4.2-py3.4.egg',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
 Server time:   Sat, 13 Sep 2014 12:18:36 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handler is raising an exception. You are trying to serialise the entire exception object to json to return to the user. Instead get a string representation of the exception and return that:

```
def receiver(request):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        response = "%s" % sys.exc_info()[0]
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response))
```

(It's not a great idea to be directly returning internal exception messages, you should probably try and specifically catch the exception and return a user-friendly message instead of the actual exception)

If you want to see *why* you are getting an exception in your code, you need to allow the exception to be raised. Get rid of the `try`..`catch` block and you will see the *actual* exception that is being raised with regards the `request_to_json` function

By the looks of it, the problem is that you are trying to serialize [the entire body of the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body):

```
 post_data = request.body
```

which `simplejson` doesn't like

Comment: all i receive now is :  ""

Comment: except:
        response = "Error" it returns Error